# ¿Cómo sacar el campo activo de una contraseña?

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, cucumber

¿Cómo sacar el campo libre en serie?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única diferencia que hay, es que cuando aparece el campo libre aparece la clase *num-coordenada active*

Este es mi código:

```
   for (int i = 0; i<signInput.size();i++){
           // identifico la contraseña que debe aparecer
            int numberSign = Integer.parseInt(signature.substring(i, i + 1));
          // si la clase es active, pulsa el campo libre
                if (signInput.get(i).getAttribute("class").equals(signInputActive.get(i).getAttribute("class"))) {
                    System.out.println("dentro1 " + numberSign);
                    clickOnTheButton(signAdvances.get(numberSign));

            }
```

El problema de este código es que solo me lo hace una vez, cuando vuelve a hacer, la condición falla.

Comment: Solucionado, añadiendo una condición mejor  for (int i = 0; i<signInput.size();i++){
            int numberSign = Integer.parseInt(signature.substring(i, i + 1));
                if (signInput.get(i).getAttribute("class").equals("num-coordenada active")) {
                    System.out.println("dentro1 " + numberSign);
                    clickOnTheButton(signAdvances.get(numberSign));

            }

Comment: Hola maestro, podrías editar tu pregunta, quitar la respuesta de ella, y agregarla en la zona correspondiente, de esa forma, no solo estarás ayudando a otros que tengan el mismo problema, sino que puede que te lleves algún puntito de reputación de regalo.

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Pon _como respuesta_ (en base a [answer]) la "solución" que mencionas, y luego [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Vas a ganar rep con tu respuesta y, lo más importante, le va a servir a otros. Como ves, en los comentarios es infumable el código y se va a perder.